# A question about a third-order homogenous linear ODE

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

Consider the ODE
$$
xy'''-2xy''+(x-1)y'+y=0
$$
wolframalpha returns the following solution:
$$
y(x) = c_2 e^x x^2 + c_3 e^x (1 - x^2) + c_1 e^x
$$
**My Question**: It seems that the solutions are spanned by
$$
\{y_1(x)=e^xx^2\ ,\ y_2(x)=e^x(x^2-1)\ ,\ y_3(x)=e^x\}
$$
But this set is linearly dependent since $y_2=y_1-y_3$. Shouldn't we suppose to have 3 linearly independent  in the basis?

Comment: For singular ODEs you cannot always expect a basis on $\mathbb{R}$. The set of solutions on $(0,\infty)$ or on $(-\infty,0)$ has dimension $3$, respectively. So in both cases there exists a third basis function. I don't know if it has an elementary form.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$$xy'''-2xy''+(x-1)y'+y=0$$
For $x \in (0,+\infty)$:
$$xy'''\color{red}{+y''-y''}-2(xy''\color{green}{+y')+2y'}+(x-1)y'+y=0$$
$$(xy'')'-y''-2(xy')'+2y'-y'+(xy)'=0$$
$$(xy'')'-y''-2(xy')'+y'+(xy)'=0$$
Integrate to reduce the order.
$$xy''-y'-2xy'+y+xy=C_1$$
Note that $y_h=e^x$  is a solution of the homogeneous DE. But you can also rewrite the DE as:
$$x(y'-y)'-(y'-y)-x(y'-y)=C_1$$
$$\left (\dfrac {y'-y}{x}\right)'-\dfrac {y'-y}x=\dfrac {C_1}{x^2}$$
$$\left (e^{-x}\dfrac {y'-y}{x}\right)'=\dfrac {C_1e^{-x}}{x^2}$$
$$\left (\dfrac {(ye^{-x})'}{x}\right)'=\dfrac {C_1e^{-x}}{x^2}$$
This is a first order DE that you can integrate ( but unfortunately not with elementary functions).

Answer (score 5):

To have a 3-dimensional space of solutions, this ODE must be solved separately on $(0,+\infty)$ and $(-\infty,0),$ as commented by @Gerd.

Letting $y=e^xz,$ it becomes
$$xz'''+xz''-z'=0,$$
i.e. $z'=u$ and
$$xu''+xu'-u=0.$$
[WolframAlpha solves it](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input?i=xy%27%27%2Bxy%27-y%3D0) and gives you the third missing solution, computable from
$$u(x)=x{\rm Ei}(-x)+e^{-x}.$$

Answer (score 4):

The o.d.e. is singular at $x = 0$, so in general the dimension of the space of solutions continuous at that point need not match the order of the equation. On the other hand, we should expect a $3$-dimensional space of solutions continuous at any point $x \neq 0$.

In our case we can solve the o.d.e. produce a third basis solution manually, though any basis extending $(e^x, x^2 e^x)$ cannot be expressed in terms of elementary functions in closed form and instead requires the exponential integral function or its equivalent.

Substituting shows that $y_1(x) = e^x$ is a solution, and substituting $y(x) = e^x u(x)$ gives
$$x u''' + x u'' - u' = 0.$$
Writing $v = u'$ reduces the system to a second-order o.d.e.,
$$x v'' + x v' - v = 0.$$
Again by inspection, $v_1(x) = x$ is a solution to this equation. Substituting $v(x) = v_1(x) w(x) = x w(x)$ gives
$$x w'' + (x + 2) w' = 0,$$
and writing $z = w'$ leaves the first-order o.d.e.,
$$x z' + (x + 2) z = 0.$$
This equation is separable and has solution
$$z(x) = \frac{K e^{-x}}{x^2}.$$
Substituting and integrating (twice) gives the general solution
$$y(x) = \boxed{A e^x + B x^2 e^x + C (x^2 e^x \operatorname{Ei}_1(x) - x + 1)},$$ of the original o.d.e. Here $\operatorname{Ei}_1(x) := \int_1^\infty \frac{e^{-tx} \,dt}{t^a}$ is defined on $(0, \infty)$ (analogous solutions can be described for $x < 0$); see the Wiki article on the [exponential integral](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Exponential_integral#Definitions).